# PHP submit issue, variables changing?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make a form for people to fill out that requests a service. They must for one of the fields enter a phone number. To ensure that the phone number is valid I have set up the PHP to send an SMS to the provided number using my providers API.

The sms sends okay and it sends with a PHP variable enclosed. (A Random int between 9999 and 99999.) This code is sent successfully but every submit the code changes as the function runs. The problem with this is that you receive the text but when you enter it in the code has already changed as you submitted the form to validate. I have tried using a button type in html but cant figure our how to run the PHP using it.
Below is the first form they fill out which sends the message.

```
<?php
$confirmcode = rand(9999, 99999);
//echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>Confirmation Code:"."<br/><br/>$confirmcode<br/><br/><br/>";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // Validation
        //Check Name is non-blank
            if( 0=== preg_match("/\S+/", $_POST['fname'])){
                $errors['first_name'] = "Please enter your name.";
            }

            if (0=== preg_match("/^[\+0-9\-\(\)\s]{10,}+$/", $_POST['phone'])){
                $errors['phone'] = "Please enter a phone number";
            }

            //Check Email has required symbols
            if (0=== preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/", $_POST['email'])){
                $errors ['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
            }
        //End Validation

    $errors = array();
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];



    //Sending Confirmation SMS code to confirm phone number.
            // Declare the security credentials to use
  $username = "############";
  $password = "############";

  // Set the attributes of the message to send
  $message  = "Hello " ."$name" ."Your confirmation code is: " ."$confirmcode".". " ."Please enter it .". "on he appraisal request form.";
  $type     = "1-way";
  $senderid = "SanctuaryRE";
  $to       = $_POST['phone'];

  // Build the URL to send the message to. Make sure the 
  // message text and Sender ID are URL encoded. You can
  // use HTTP or HTTPS
  $url = "http://api.directsms.com.au/s3/http/send_message?" .
         "username=" . $username . "&" .
         "password=" . $password . "&" .
         "message="  . urlencode($message) . "&" .
         "type="     . $type . "&" .
         "senderid=" . urlencode($senderid) . "&" .
         "to="       . $to;

  // Send the request
  $output = file($url);

  // The response from the gateway is going to look like 
  // this:
  // id: a4c5ad77ad6faf5aa55f66a
  // 
  // In the event of an error, it will look like this:
  // err: invalid login credentials
  $result = explode(":", $output[0]);
    //END SMS


  header("Location: process.php");
}

?>
```

And the form they are pushed onto to confirm the code they were sent.

```
<html>
<div class="wrapper2">
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="textfieldlong" placeholder="Confirmation Code" name="giventoken"> 
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Verify Phone Number" name="submit2" id="submit2"> 
</form>
</html>

<style>
.wrapper{
    display:none;
}
</style>
</div>

<?php
include "index.php";
    //$token = $_POST['giventoken'];
    //if (!strcmp($confirmcode,$token)){
    //  echo "Match";
    //}

echo "$confirmcode";
?>
```

The random int is generated right at the beginning. Please help! Thnx. :D

Comment: What if the user refreshes the page? or closes the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random number is being created every time.

You will have to database the number for each specific user and then check when they enter the code. You cant expect the user to get the text and confirm immediately. The only real way to do this is to database it.

Setup a table with the userid and the code, then check when they confirm that you sent that code to that user.

Comment: Ok I will try that thanks. I cant except your answer to soon it wont let me but I will mark as correct when I can.